# Angular2 FullCalendar callback inaccessible properties

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I have an angular2 app where i have a Full Calendar component. I want to display a dialog on click of a full calendar event using the `eventClick` callback. I have the following code to do this:

```
export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit{

events: CalendarEvent[];
display: boolean;
tables: SelectItem[];
selectedTable: string;

ngOnInit(){
    this.display = false;
    this.scheduleService.GetAllEvents().subscribe((data: CalendarEvent[]) => 
            { 
                this.events = data;
                var calendar: JQuery = $("#calendar");
                (<any>calendar).fullCalendar({
                    eventClick: function(event) {
                        this.display = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
}
```

}

This is a very simplified version but should give all the information needed.

My problem is that the `this.display = true` line inside the `eventClick` callback does not seem to be able  to see the `display` property.

Does anyone know why this is and how i could fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically after posting a question, i have now worked out a resolution.

The solution for anyone else struggling with this is to use the 'fat arrow' notation.

So instead of this:

```
eventClick: function(event) {
                        this.display = true;
                        return false;
                    }
```

I used this:

```
eventClick: (event) => {
                        this.display = true;
                        return false;
                    },
```

Im not too sure how this works as it was just trial and error. So if anyone does know why and can explain it then i would be very interested to find out why.

Comment: The fat arrow notation in Typescript when converted to javascript on compile gives a reference to the parent 'this' you will see it in your .js file as var _this = this; then the subsequent function code uses the reference  _this.display = true.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge you were facing had something to do with scope.
At runtime the value of this changes and there fore display wont be accessible.

Lexical scoping is one of the ways you can solve this and thats what you have done above.

You can also bind the context of the method to the this so it executes within that context.

You can do this using the javascript bind method